# View Component in own assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Target Platform: ASP.Core/.Net 5.0

I have a view component library that I am trying to move out of my application as a standalone class library. Originally, I had the full path of Razor View that my vc was calling and everything was working. The view then internally calls another relevant view in the same substructure. After moving to the class library, I am unable to get around the view not found error. Below is my vc substructure.
[Class Library substructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/309fu.png)

Call Pattern: ViewComponent --> View/LayoutDrawer.cshtml --> View/Native/.cshtml

**VC InvokeAsync Method**

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ObviateShotCaller sc)
        {

            Printer.print($"Obviates: \"{sc.RenderClassType.Name}\" for layout: {sc.LayoutFor}");
            if (sc is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sc));
            }

            sc.Options = options;
            //sc.Engine.PopulateDataContracts(this);
            //string viewName = Path.Combine($"./Views/LayoutDrawer{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
            return await Task.Run(() => View("/Views/LayoutDrawer.cshtml", sc));
        }
```

**Based on information on few other threads, I added these to my project file:**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views/**/*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Finally, I added the reference to the class assembly in my target project and changed startup to include

```
  services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ObviateViewComponent).Assembly);
```

I am still getting the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Obviate//Views/LayoutDrawer.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/LayoutDrawer.cshtml
```

From the looks of it, The razor engine is trying to search for the view in current project rather than the library. Would appreciate any help on how I can fix this.

**Update[Solved]**

I managed to get one solution to work.

1. Changed the way I call view..

```
return await Task.Run(() => View("LayoutDrawer", sc));
```

2. Moved the directory structure in class library as follows: [new directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1G4Z.png)
3. Installed the MvcRazorRuntimeCompilation package, and added the following to startup:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => {
                options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(ObviateViewComponent).Assembly,"Obviate"));
            });
        }
```

Though the AddRazorRuntimeCompilation looks to be slower. Any other way to do this?

Comment: this `Task.Run(() => View("/Views/LayoutDrawer.cshtml", sc))` is clearly wrong, the first parameter is ***view name*** not view path. That's why you have the message `The view 'Components/Obviate//Views/LayoutDrawer.cshtml' was not found` - actually it derives for the name as `Components/Obviate/{view_name}`. Your update works maybe because you tried ***embedding*** your view files into the library assembly. Still it's strange that your original code works.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code to indicate that I am passing filename now. Although, view does take absolute and relative paths. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: actually that's the View concept in `mvc` (can be targeted by using `Controller.View` method), but the view you use here is in `ViewComponent`, can be targeted by using `ViewComponent.View` method as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewComponent_View__1_System_String___0_ It requires ***view name***, view path makes no sense because anyway it's just treated as a name and will not be used for searching your view like a relative path.

Comment: Well before I moved to an external library I was using a full path to view along with .cshtml to make things work (couldnt get around the search path). It definitely worked.

Comment: you can retry it yourself to confirm if *it definitely worked*. I've personally been like that many times and actually there have been times I was too self-confident. From the document for `Controller.View` method, the `viewName` is clearly described as ***The name or path of the view that is rendered to the response.*** whereas for the `ViewComponent.View`, it's just ***The name of the partial view to render.***. Note that `mvc` has a convention of folder structures in pair of controller & view, the relative view path can make sense when the base path can be derived from the controller class.